# Unable to install psycopg2 on mac

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, pip, psycopg2

I have installed the latest version of postgresql on my mac using "pip install postgresql". I have also installed libpq on my mac and it contains all header files needed for psycopg2. I have searched for all prerequisities that psycopg2 needs them but when i try to install it using pip3 install psycopg2 i got a lot of errors and can't find any resolution for that. I read a lot of answers and site helps but nothing helped me. The following are the errors i have encountered.

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: You can try `pip install psycopg2-binary` instead – they're prebuilt wheels that might work better for you here.

Comment: Is there any problem with working with binary version? or everything will be the same as using psycopg2?

Comment: You _might_ encounter errors if psycopg2-binary has been compiled against a different version of a library than that present on your machine - I had this with openSSL once - but it's relatively rare in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use "pipenv" to prepare a virtual environment in Python without using "pip", and I think you can create it without being affected by other environments.
I'll show you how to create a simple virtual environment.

```
pip install pipenv #Installation of pipenv

cd [Development directory] #Move to the directory you are developing

pipenv install --python 3.6.8 #Specify the version you want to use

pipenv install psycopg2 #Install the package

pipenv shell #Enter the virtual environment
```